# How can I make managed federation work offline?

Tags: apollo, apollo-server, apollostack, apollo-federation

I wanted to set up Apollo Studio for an Apollo Federation API following [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/managed-federation/setup/) guide. In there I stumbled upon the following sentence regarding the `serviceList` in the gateway:

> With managed federation, this information is no longer hardcoded in the gateway's constructor! Instead, the gateway regularly polls Apollo for this information.

While I do get that this does have its benefits I was wondering if I can still leave the `serviceList` there and test my API when I do not have an internet connection. Of course I wouldn't have the ability to use Apollo Studio without an internet connection (at least I think so), but I would like to be able to work on my API when I'm offline. If not, how can I use Apollo Studio anyways? I would like to use the performance metrics feature.

Thanks for your help!

-Moritz